# How do I run a google apps script from my account, in the context of another user that I have creds to?

Tags: google-apps-script

For example, my son's gmail account. I have creds. I have permission. How can I run a script that will do things in my Google account and do things in his? (For example, access his Google Classroom, grab all assignments, and list them in my Google sheet)?

Comment: Just share the resources between accounts.

Comment: Or publish a webapp: Execute as "User accessing". Use your son's account to provide access to his resources

Comment: By share resources, do you mean something like sharing a spreadsheet?